# Ancestor binding ComboBox ItemsSource within ListView Data Template

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox, datatemplate

I have this code in my view.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="White">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMethod.Commands}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid},AncestorLevel=1}, 
                                           Path=DataContext.MethodEventFunctions}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding FunctionName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And this code behind:

```
public MethodViewModel SelectedMethod
{
    get { return _selectedMethod; }
    set
    {
        _selectedMethod = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}        

public List<string> MethodEventFunctions { get; private set; }

public class MethodViewModel
{
    public List<MethodBindingViewModel> Commands
    {
        get { return _commands; }
        set
        {
            _commands = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I fill `MethodEventFunctions` in `ViewModel` constructor. Then I select method, but `ComboBox` stay empty.
But if I change `ListView` to `ListBox` it's all OK. Where I have a problem?

This code also give me a empty ComboxBox.

```
 <Grid Name="GridMain" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="White">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMethod.Commands}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid},AncestorLevel=1}, 
                                       Path=DataContext.MethodEventFunctions}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You shouldn't place your view models in the code-behind. Also, it's unclear what `Locator` and `Main` are.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried to lookup the visual tree? As you bind to `AncestorType={x:Type Grid}` this may causing it to work in `ListBox`. This is also very bad practice. You should really bind to the ViewModel not to some ancestor grid.